# return MIN(DATE) and other existing date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return all the minimum dates of every single clients in the table and display it as "FIRST" if it is the MIN date, and IF its not,  it will return "OTHER"

this is my query

```
 SELECT TRANS_DATE, IF(TRANS_DATE= MIN(TRANS_DATE), 'FIRST', 'OTHER') AS TR_CODE
 FROM `posthis`
 WHERE datepost IS NOT NULL
```

My query only returns the MIN()

[image]

this is the result that I need

```
 CLIENTID               TRANS_DATE       TR_CODE

 02-00002234            2002-02-01       FIRST

 02-00002234            2002-02-02       OTHER

 02-00002234            2002-02-03       OTHER

 02-00002235            2003-01-03       FIRST

 02-00002235            2003-01-05       OTHER

 02-00002235            2003-01-06       OTHER

 02-00002236            2003-01-03       FIRST

 02-00002236            2003-01-04       OTHER

 02-00002236            2003-01-13       OTHER
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `MIN()` as an analytic function would really come in handy for your problem.  But since MySQL does not support this, we can use a join instead.  In the query below, I `LEFT JOIN` the `posthis` table to a subquery which identifies the earliest date for each client.  Should a record in `posthis` match to this subquery, we label it with a code `'FIRST'`, otherwise we label `'OTHER'`.

```
SELECT
    t1.CLIENTID,
    t1.TRANS_DATE,
    CASE WHEN t2.CLIENTID IS NOT NULL THEN 'FIRST' ELSE 'OTHER' END AS TR_CODE
FROM posthis t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT CLIENTID, MIN(TRANS_DATE) AS MIN_TRANS_DATE
    FROM posthis
    GROUP BY CLIENTID
) t2
    ON t1.CLIENTID   = t2.CLIENTID AND
       t1.TRANS_DATE = t2.MIN_TRANS_DATE
```

Comment: sir, your answer will return the min date of every single client. But for every year..  All I need is to return the whole transaction date for every single client and it will return FIRST for the 1st date of transaction.

Comment: Update your question and show data which clearly illustrates what you want.  I have answered the question which is currently posted.